# Русская походка?

Tags: значение-слов, определения

В воспоминании И. С. Тургенева о друге — художнике Александре Ивáнове — есть такие строчки:

> Роста он был небольшого, приземист, плечист; вся его фигура, от бородки клинушком до пухлых, короткопалых ручек и проворных ножек с толстыми икрами — дышала Русью, и ходил он русской походкой.

Русская походка, она какая? В ней есть своя пластика или особый характер?

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150004/discussion-on-question-by-shampar--); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.